# Is it possible to get an LPT timeout lower than 1 second?

Tags: windows, 16-bit, lpt

Windows XP - 10 have [a setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959496.aspx) to control the max time a 16-bit application can have an LPT port open. The registry value for that setting seems to only understand integer values greater than zero.

Is there any way to make those connections limited to any fraction of second?

Comment: Probably not. Why would you want to anyway?

Comment: Frenzy working on a store with an old program which because of this, opens the cash drawer with a delay of one-two seconds